# Capture a terminal output in real time of an python module

Tags: python-3.x, module, subprocess, real-time, yfinance

The python 'yfinance' module downloads the quotes of many Financial Securities in a pandas dataframe and in the meanwhile it displays a progress bar in the console. In this way:

```
import yfinance as yf
Tickerlist = ["AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"]
quote = yf.download(tickers=Tickerlist,period='max',interval='1d',group_by='ticker')
```

I would like to capture the console progress bar in real time, and the code should be this:

```
import sys
import subprocesss
process = subprocess.Popen(["yf.download","tickers=Tickerlist","period='max'","interval='1d'","group_by='ticker'"],stdout=quote)
while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write(out)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I make a big mess with subprocess. I need your help! Thanks.
I have already seen all the links that deal with this topic but without being able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two python files to do what you want.

one is yf_download.py and second is run.py

The file code looks like this and you can run it through run.py

> python run.py

yf_download.py

```
import sys
import yfinance as yf

Tickerlist = ["AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"]

def run(period):
    yf.download(tickers=Tickerlist, period=period,interval='1d',group_by='ticker')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    period = sys.argv[1]
    run(period)
```

run.py

```
import sys
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "yf_download.py", "max"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    if process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks roy cha, it seems ok, but when it ends the program does not close. Inside the PyCharm editor I have to manually end it with a following "Process finished with exit code -1".